# Why Vaadin-maven-plugin run with multiple versions?

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a maven project with `vaadin 14.1.25` and `Java EE 7` which creates a `.war` file.
When I run or build project I see different version of vaadin-maven-pluging is proceeding.

```
Such as in attached picture below:

 1. vaadin-maven-pluging: 14.1.17
 2. vaadin-maven-pluging: 14.1.19
 3. vaadin-maven-pluging: 15.0.0
```

I have only one maven plugin in my project which is `vaadin-maven-pluging: 14.1.25`.

**Can someone explain why does it happen?**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>it.uz.counting</groupId>
    <artifactId>counting-web</artifactId>

    <version>1.0.95-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>counting-web</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>iso-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin-version> 
        <!-- Web -->
        <!-- Trinidad -->
        <trinidad.version>2.2.1</trinidad.version>
        <tomahawk.version>1.1.14</tomahawk.version>
        <vaadin.version>14.1.25</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.productionMode>false</vaadin.productionMode>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>7.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-cdi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.uz.counting</groupId>
            <artifactId>counting-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.95-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>

<!-- Web -->
        <!-- Trinidad -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad</groupId>
            <artifactId>trinidad-api</artifactId>
            <version>${trinidad.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomahawk20</artifactId>
            <version>${tomahawk.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Primefaces-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi Version 3.13 is compatible with primeface 6.2-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
            <!-- <version>4.2.2</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Primefaces Themes Library https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces.themes/all-themes-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces.extensions/master-pom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>master-pom</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.9</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces.extensions/resources-codemirror -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources-codemirror</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- End primeFace -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web Services Description Language -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        WEB-INF/lib/xmlParserAPIs-2.0.2.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/xml-apis-1.3.02.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/pdf-renderer-1.0.5.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/jfreechart-1.0.1.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/jempbox-1.6.0.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/jdtcore-3.2.0.v_658.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/jcommon-1.0.16.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/informix-driver-3.0.jar,

                        WEB-INF/lib/commons-validator-1.3.1.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-1.3.2.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/bcmail-jdk14-1.38.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-1.45.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/batik-util-1.6-1.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/batik-gui-util-1.6-1.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/batik-ext-1.6-1.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/batik-awt-util-1.6-1.jar,

                        WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar

                        WEB-INF/lib/junit-3.8.1.jar

                    </packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--  Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports.   It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                            <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your full `pom.xml`? You can also run `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out which plugin/dependency transitively depends on version `15.0.0`.

Comment: I think you tried to anonymize your company's info, but you left it in at least 3 different places.

Comment: @JacobG. I have updated with pom.xml